# How can high-tech person move to a fantasy world?

Tags: humans, robots, cyborg, conflict

**What are conditions for a high-tech person (robot, cyborg or so) could move to a fantasy world?**

Even if my world is a fantasy world, it is only one part of a huge universe where other worlds (and civilisations) are very technically advanced - and some of them are advanced enough to be robotic, or at least cybernetic.

And from these very advanced civilisations, few people visit the fantasy world - for some peaceful purposes (saving their own world and saving this world from destruction).

Under what conditions will a high-tech person move to a fantasy world? How to allow for their presence?

**Edit:**

Basically even if these high-tech people disguise themselves as local people, they will get caught and examined. And then it will be necessary to explain the existence of visitors' form of *life* on the fantasy planet. Since their high-tech life-form isn't supported on the fantasy planet.  (Otherwise such forms of life will already be present on the planet and because the local people know about their planet's many forms of life, from people and animals to flowers and this included the magic creatures called Shining Ones).

Comment: Not very clear on what is being asked here? Is the fantasy world on the same planet? the same Universe? A Parallel Universe? A Multiverse?

Comment: Should be summoned as demon by local wizards. It more or less worked in an RPG that I played, I had plenty of fun that my character refused to consider fantasy setting and was desperately looking for Wi-Fi in some magic faux ancient China.

Comment: Is "how can they remain undetected" a bit more apt after the edit?

Comment: I'm confused, what exactly is being asked?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking "HOW", then the answer is purely technological. Spaceships, time capsules, anything sill do.

If you're asking about how they would behave when they get there, then I suppose the motiv is the important part.

Is it for scientifical purposes ? Exploration ? Then the "star trek" approach, where the top priority is to preserve the balance of the visited world (mainly by not being seen), seems the way to go.

Is it for expansion/colonization ? Then a military approach would be more suitable. If you factor in the advantage given by technology, you can also tweak  the amount of destruction/aggression needed. Do you want to enslave the locals ? Is your technology on par with their magic/sorcery ? Can one be disguised as the other ?

Did they get there randomly following some sort of accident ? then a more survivalistic approach should fit in well.

I guess in this case, the "HOW" really really depends on the "WHY".

Comment: This is however not an answer, just commentary.